# lwuit flashbacklight

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am using LWUIT to construct an application. In LWUIT , one can flash a backlight of a cellphone with the following command:

`Display.getInstance().flashbacklight();`

The frequency at which the backlight flashes is pretty low.

How do I make the backlight flash faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must call `Display.getInstance.flashBacklight(int duration);` so many times. Try to insert this method inside a while (or in a cyclic `Thread`) and use small value to the duration.